Can a non-profit discriminate members by family status?
Years ago our family joined a non-profit "community" organization offering gym, kindergarten, and other activities. The membership fees vary depending on whether the member is a) single; b) a single-parent; c) a part of a household.
When joining, we had multiple household members taking advantage of what the organization had to offer, but now for the last two years I'm the only one.
When I asked to change my membership to that of the single person, the organization asked, whether we've had a divorce or a separation... Upon learning, that we haven't, they insisted, that, as long as I remain part of a household, I must pay the household fee -- regardless of whether any other household member has any interest in partaking.
Clearly, this is discrimination -- I'm asked to pay about twice the rate of a single person, because I have a family. But is this discrimination illegal?

Are the other members of your former household are still eligible to use the services?

They are eligible, but aren't interested -- and yet, the organization wouldn't let me end their membership simply because we're all in the same household.

If they weren't interested when they were in your household, could you have purchased an individual membership?

@Barmar, the household members were interested 10+ years ago, when we joined. They lost the interest by now. And, no, it was not possible for me to buy a single-person membership -- the organization asked, whether or not I'm a single back then.

It's too late now, but you almost certainly could have gotten away with telling them you were divorced. What are they going to do, check the court records?

I didn't want to lie... Moreover, I'm sufficiently mad, that I'd look for a lawyer to sue them over it -- if the community convinces me, the practice is illegal. Meanwhile, I'm changing switching to another organization...

Wow, three downvotes... What's with the hate?.. Did people recognize the non-profit I'm talking about -- and took offense? :-)

@MikhailT., no, you're getting downvoted because the question is worded like a request for specific legal advice, which isn't permitted on this site.

No, @Mark, my question clearly asks: "is this discrimination illegal?" And the sole -- and deservingly up-voted -- answer answers that question... Frankly, I suspect, you and I are members of the same non-profit -- even if you feel differently about their practices.

The non-profit can discriminate based upon family status.
It isn't housing, where this kind of discrimination is limited. And, it isn't any other category of service where discrimination based upon family status is prohibited. It probably isn't even a "public accommodation" (since it is "member's only").
Also, many non-profits like this are religiously based (such as the YMCA or a Jewish Community Center) and have additional freedom of religion protections from government interference.
